# Show that all center of curvature to the curve  = sin²x/x² at its points of contact with the -axis lie on a parabola. How to solve this problem?

Tags: calculus, curvature

Can someone please help me solve this question. I tried to solve it by finding the radius of the curvature but the derivatives are huge. Is there any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let observe that in the parabola $y=ax^2$ the center of curvature in the vertex is $r=1/2a.$

Similarly, for the function
$$
f(x)=\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}
$$
it is enough to make a second order approximation in the minima, i.e
$$
f(x)=\frac{(x-k\pi)^2}{(k\pi)^2}+o(x-k\pi)^2 
$$
so the radius in $M_k=(k\pi,0)$ is $r_k=1/2a=(k\pi)^2/2$ and the centers are
$$
C_k=\left(k\pi,\frac{(k\pi)^2}{2}\right)
$$

Comment: [+1] Excellent answer.

Comment: @Jean Marie, thank you